# Web Performance Test - could not load type 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.WebTesting.SharepointInformation'

Tags: c#, web-testing

I installed VS.2017 Enterprise and start a web performance project. When I try to add a Web performance test to the project I receive the error:

> "The Web test could not be loaded: Could not load the type
>   'Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.WebTesting.SharepointInformation'
>   from assembly 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.WebTestFramework'
>   Version=10.0.0.0, .."

Comment: At what point, precisely, in the addition of a test is the error reported? Please [edit] the question after reading the [help] pages and doing the [tour].

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**TL;DR:**

1. Check installed prerequisites in the latter part of [Create a web performance and load test project](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/test/performance-testing/run-performance-tests-app-before-release#createtests)
2. In my case, **replacing original file**
   *C:\windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.WebTestFramework\10.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.WebTestFramework.dll*
   **with**
   *C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\ReferenceAssemblies\v4.0\Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.WebTestFramework.dll* **solved the problem.**

---

I tackled the same issue. Every time I created Web Performance and Load Test Project in Visual Studio 2017 Enterprise (with arbitrary .NET framework version) I got the same error when I tried to open *.webtest file. VS's user interface seemed incomplete and clicking on toolbars sometimes shown null exceptions.

At first, I thought I have incomplete installation, according to [Create a web performance and load test project](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/test/performance-testing/run-performance-tests-app-before-release#createtests). I have even tried to completely uninstall and reinstall mentioned packages. Unfortunately, this did not help. I have also experimented with adding and removing reference to *Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.WebTestFramework* as there are several options in my reference browser, but without success.

There is not much information about *WebTesting.SharepointInformation* namespace. After a while, I discovered the existence of *Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.WebTest.SharePoint.dll* and after closer inspection, I have noticed that it references *QualityTools.WebTestFramework* assembly in *C:\Windows\assembly\...* that has the same assembly version and public key token, yet smaller in size compared to the one that is contained in VS 2017 installation. **I have replaced it with VS2017's one and voila, *.webtest can be successfully opened.**

Comment: This perfectly solved my issue. To bypass administrative access leading to "Access is denied: ‘xxx.dll’" when updating update DLLs, check this post: https://stepbistep.net/2012/06/26/access-is-denied-xxx-dll-manually-add-an-assembly-dll-to-the-gac-on-windows-server-2008-r2/

Answer (score 0):

The above answer is correct but the problem is the directory isn't accessible in my case due to some reasons so I just open my cmd and run this command. Just run, it will copy the file, but first turn of the vs.

```
copy "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\ReferenceAssemblies\v4.0\Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.WebTestFramework.dll" "C:\windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.WebTestFramework\10.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a"
```